# Github API: Create a new repo from an existing one under same organisation

Tags: java, github, github-api

I want to create a new repository in github from an existing repository or from a specific branch of an existing repository under same organisation.

So, I have the repository my-app and from which I want to fork/copy my-app-new under same organisation.

And I want to do this using github APIs.

Now, there is a [Fork API](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/repos#create-a-fork), but that is not possible under same branch as we can't rename the repo while forking.

Therefore,
are the following things possible:

1. copy the entire repo with a new name under same org
2. copy only a specific branch from existing repo to a new repo under same org